# SR Latch by NAND gates with no inputs applied

Tags: digital-logic

If the latch is just powered and no input is given, what happens? Do the outputs become logic level 1 and stay that way until a voltage is applied at any of the inputs?

Comment: Place two coins, one with heads upward to the left and one with tails upward to the right of you, on a table in front of you. Now, when anyone comes by and changes the coin on the left's upward face, you should change the upward side of the coin on the right to be the opposite. You have a NOT gate. How is this possible? Because you have to be fed to supply your *idling energy* to sit there and monitor things and the *active* energy needed to flip the coin over when needed. A real gate also needs access to power/energy. It's in the nature of things. You've merely forgotten this detail.

Comment: Are you suggesting you've been looking at NOT gate (inverter) ICs and not found any power pins on it? C'mon, this is two minutes on Google...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every logic gate have a power supply. This mean that the input doesn't supply the gate. That's why it's possible to have a voltage at the output without voltage at the input.

As you can see on this chip, a voltage supply is present (pin 14) : 
[image]

Or, when the gate is made with transistor, the output voltage isn't provide by the input but by the GND or the supply :

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2frJUo8.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>